# Recreating palindromes

Tags: palindrome

In this puzzle, I am offering you the paraphases of English palindromic phrases. That is, I take a phrase:

> Egad, a base tone denotes a bad age!

replace each fragment of the phrase with synonymous expressions:

> My god, a low voice is the hallmark of elderness!

**Recreate** the initial palindromic phrases from the paraphrases below.

1. Return to such a peaceful position and meditate.
2. Medic, rescue the antique amphoras and escape!
3. The god of lightning ascended and noticed the strait of Egypt.
4. Stand up and express your choice, noble man.
5. If you meet mice, do not be afraid and do not signal approval.
6. Is it time for the sweethearts to rebel?
7. Wrong, a shiny ingot won't be a good building block for a fortress.

The line of reasoning for the example one may be as follows:

> *Elderness* may have to do with *age*, so we should have *... age* at the end of the phrase. It should start with *Ega...* then, and we're looking for a swear expression similar to *My god*. 
>  Next, we have *voice*. Looking for synonyms for *voice*, we have *sound*, *pitch* or *tone*. Reverting the letter order, it's *dnuos*, *hctip* or *enot*. Only the last one makes sense as a part of a word, so we'll stick to that.
>  Now, we look for words and expressions that have *enot* and match the meaning of *hallmark*. After a while, we come up with *denote*.

EDIT: Whoa, cracked in an hour. Should I do more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)

> Resume so pacific a pose, muser.

2)

> Nurse, save rare vases, run!

3)

> Zeus was deified, saw Suez.

4)

> Rise to vote, Sir.

5)

> Do not start at rats to nod.

6)

> INCORRECT Are we not drawn onwards, we Jews, drawn onward to new era? CORRECT Won't lovers revolt now?

7)

> No, it's a bar of gold, a bad log for a bastion.

From https://www.cs.arizona.edu/icon/oddsends/palinsen.htm

Comment: @svavil "Won't lovers revolt now?"???

Comment: @manshu Exactly.